# Select latest 30 dates for each unique ID

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

This is a sample data file
[image: dateinfo]

Data Contains unique IDs with different latitudes and longitudes on multiple timestamps.I would like to select the rows of latest 30 days of coordinates for each unique ID.Please help me on how to run the query .This date is in Hive table

Regards,
Akshay

Comment: You have tagged 4 RDBMS which ONE do you want an answer for

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Also, databases store data in *tables* not *files*.

Comment: Logic: Get the max(date) for each id and then return all rows with a date >= max(date) -30. Implementation is based on the DBMS: either a Correlated Subquery or Windowed Aggregates.

Comment: sorry for the confusion i am currently writing this query to extract data from hive tables.

Answer (score 1):

According to your example above (where no current year dates for id=2,3), you can numbering date for each id (order by date descending) using window function `ROW_NUMBER()`. Then just get latest 30 values:

```
--get all values for each id where num<=30 (get last 30 days for each day)
select * from
(
--numbering each date for each id order by descending
  select *, row_number()over(partition by ID order by DATE desc)num from Table
)X
where num<=30
```

If you need to get only *unique dates *(without consider time)** for each id, then can try this query:

```
select * from
(
 --numbering date for each id
 select *, row_number()over(partition by ID order by new_date desc)num
 from
  (
   -- move duplicate using distinct
   select  distinct ID,cast(DATE as date)new_date  from Table
  )X
)Y
where num<=30
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from MyTable 
where
  [Date]>=dateadd(d, -30, getdate());
```

To group by ID and perform aggregation, something like this

```
select ID, 
       count(*) row_count,
       max(Latitude) max_lat,
       max(Longitude) max_long
from MyTable 
where
  [Date]>=dateadd(d, -30, getdate())
group by ID;
```

Comment: thank you @SteveC,how could we groupby by ID and get 30 days data for each ID.

Comment: Hi, I updated to include an example using aggregation :)

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle this will be:

```
SELECT * FROM TEST_DATE1
WHERE DATEUPDT > SYSDATE - 30;
```